# How to use Git to monitor file changes in production servers without affecting performance?

Tags: git, server, production, file-monitoring

We have a production system with multiple servers that we access with a shared login account. We are a team of three and we can login simultaneously. However, this makes it hard to track who made what changes and when, especially for configuration files that can affect the production application operation.

We want to use Git to monitor the changes in these files, but we don’t want to track the log files. We also want to monitor multiple folders on each server.

How can we set up Git for this purpose? What are the best practices and potential pitfalls? How can we ensure that using Git does not affect the performance of our production applications?

We have not tested this in the QA environment because it does not simulate the same operations as the production environment.

Disclaimer: Question was improved using ChatGPT :)

Comment: Probably best to have a configuration repo where all those people have access; then add a deploy pipeline to roll out the changed configuration to the respective server/folders. Then you'd have a clear history of who change what and who applied the new configuration at what point of time.

Comment: @Jay Will this work on an environment where there at least minimum 400MB of different files?